# Replace substring in string using python

Tags: python, string, excel, loops

I have `csv` data

```
url
vk.com/feed
vk.com/friends
vk.com/kobrinsky
vk.com/exclusive_muzic
vk.com/o_gordievskaya
vk.com/exclusive_muzic
vk.com/o_gordievskaya
```

And I need replace some substring.

```
[u'o_gordievskaya', u'pavel__pechenkin', u'tima555102', u'bl2225554445']
```

to

```
[23183634, 86313977, 27313686, 3935697]
```

I try

```
users = pd.read_excel('users.xlsx')
data = pd.read_csv('get_id.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
scrname = users['scrname']
id_scr = users['id']
urls = data['url']
for url in urls:
    for scr in scrname:
        if scr in url:
            url.replace(scr, id_scr)
```

I add column `scrname` and `id` to lists, I think it would be easier, but it doesn't help me

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?  What's wrong about your current solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `id_scr` in the replace but you need to use the corresponding element

```
index = url.index(scr)    
url.replace(scr, id_scr[index])
```

or shorter :

```
url.replace(scr, id_scr[url.index(scr)])
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because in `for url in urls:` url is a copy of your data.

But since you use pandas, you can simply use replace

```
sub = {'o_gordievskaya' :23183634, 'pavel__pechenkin' : 86313977, ...}
data.replace(sub)
```